# Retrieving PayPal billing/customer agreements

Tags: paypal

Is there a way at the moment to retrieve all PayPal billing agreements automatically? I understand that the API only currently allows retrieving individual billing agreements details by providing a specific ID.

At the moment, our workaround is to login to the [merchant page](https://business.paypal.com/merchantdata/reportHome) and go to the recurring payments, create a report, and download the generated report. We would then parse the report to retrieve the billing agreement information. The problem with this solution is that we would have manual intervention to login to merchant page. Is there a way to generate a user session programmatically and be able to download the generated report?

We could perform logging in to the page using some automation tools such as puppeteer but we would like to use that only as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

There is no PayPal API that lists agreements. Download the report if you need a current list, and subscribe to webhooks if you need to be notified of changes as they happen.